# How to increase my Ubuntu Memory from 4Gig to 16G

Tags: virtualization, ram

I already deployed my Ubuntu on my Window 7 dual partition, I only allocated about 4Gig of memory out of 32G memory. I need to increase my Ubuntu  memory to run another VM instance. How can I increase my Ubuntu memory?

Comment: Are you having ubuntu in a VM or are you dual booting? Please clarify your question.

Comment: You said memory, but did you really mean disk space?  Do you really only have 32gb of disk space?

Answer (score 1):

1. In VirtualBox select the Ubuntu guest OS.
2. In the VirtualBox toolbar click the gear-shaped Settings icon.
3. In the left pane select *System*.
4. Select the *Motherboard* tab.
5. Move the *Base Memory* slider which controls the amount of memory provided to the virtual machine from 4GB to 16GB.

[image]

6. Click the *OK* button in the lower right corner.

The steps for changing the base memory of the guest OS are similar for VMware and Windows Virtual PC. As a rule of thumb the base memory allocated to the guest OS should not exceed 50% of the available physical RAM. If you are running multiple guest OSs at the same time, the base memory allocated to all of the currently running guest OSs together should not exceed 50% of the available physical RAM. If you assign too much memory to the virtual machine, the machine may might  not be able to start.